# Kogito: Is it possible to embed Kogito DMN editor in a web application?

Tags: kie-workbench, dmn, kogito

In my project, I use DMN to model rules which gets executed using the drools DMN engine along with java code. It is expected to have 1000+ DMN rules in the project. I am trying to find a way to manage these DMN rules. Currently business-central is used to build these DMN rules and then it is downloaded to the project folder. As one DMN model has dependency on other, it is getting hard to import and export DMNs in business-central. I am planning to build a web application which will help to manage these DMN rules.

- Is there any tool that helps to manage the DMN rules so that I don't have to build one?
- I have explored kogito online DMN editor, is it possible to embed the DMN editor inside other web application (Iframe or npm package). If possible, does it have APIs for interaction like loading a DMN and saving?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, for which I invite you to start a conversation on the [Drools-usage mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-usage) and/or the [Kogito mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kogito-development).

It seems you are looking to manage the whole project as a ***web application***, in terms of assets (DMNs, etc.) and their dependencies. I assume this will need features like versioning, access control, etc. all features which are covered already by Business Central.

I would advise you should try to rely on Business Central as much as possible, and customise only the parts which are necessary. For instance you can use APIs to export the project locally if needed, etc.

Kogito editors are more oriented for a developer experience (for instance integration with VS Code), not about serving project management as a web application (that is the focus of Business Central). That said Kogito editor offer a BPMN editor and DMN editor as a Chrome extension as well, which can be beneficial if your "project management" needs can be handled by github.

The choice depends really on many factors and what features are required by the web application you mention, how many of the features are you looking to leverage from the existing projects or reimplement yourself.

I recommend for you to continue this discussion on the suggested mailing-list as this is a very broad question which can better benefit from an iterative exchange.